# Web scraping impossible login?

Tags: python, session, web-scraping

I've been trying to login into a website using python sessions requests but really having trouble.

1. I access the website and retrieve cookies for next requests
   successfully,
2. the thing is there is a popup window with cookie consent.
3. It will only let me login if I consent I believe(this is the
   behaviour in the manual procedure)
4. I tracked the cookie consent url requests through network tab in
   google chrome inspect,
5. Upon clicking the consent cookie button **facebook pixel** and **google
   fundingchoicesmessages** urls are called with multiple parameters that
   I don't how to generate(yet at least)

The urls:

- https://www.facebook.com/tr/...parameters... (called twice)
- https://fundingchoicesmessages.google.com/f/...parameters... (called multiple times 5+)

edit:

Have anyone managed to get through this? I've been around this for some days,

### <strike>really didn't want to use selenium cause it seems to take over the mouse and keayboard and I can't continue what I'm doing in my computer</strike>

.
Any advice?

### Selenium Rocks

Selenium doesn't take over the mouse/keyboard. It runs smoothly on a dedicated browser window and meanwhile you can continue working.

thanks

Comment: Enjoy it ;) (my first web-browsing/automation project was an Instagram bot if you want to try, but you better create a secondary account to test, and give requests and click times like if it were a person)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use selenium, see examples below:

- [install chromedriver W10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150351/how-do-i-install-chromedriver-on-windows-10-and-run-selenium-tests-with-chrome)
- linux

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
pip3 install selenium
```

- [fill-username-and-password-using-selenium-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186327/fill-username-and-password-using-selenium-in-python)
- [python-selenium-how-to-login-to-a-website-with-a-login-redirect-organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901290/python-selenium-how-to-login-to-a-website-with-a-login-redirect-organization)
- [selenium official documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Doesn't selenium make impossible to use other programs in the computer tho? I thought it would take over the mouse and keyboard hmm

Comment: You can even run a `headless` selenium session so you will not even see the program working. And don't worry selenium webdriver will not take over the mouse and keyboad.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna take a look and see if I get this one rolling :)

Comment: You will see how nice is automate this things with selenium, as you can see what is happening all the time with your code.